# please help me; my galaxy s duos2 keeps restarting

Tags: google-play-store, adb, recovery-mode

I used wiping data by booting menu but that doesn't made any thing
I can't do anything because the phone always restarting within 15 seconds
I have installed firmware via "install ADB from sd card" but also nothing happened
another thing i can't ticking  usb debugging mode because its rebooting too fast
"com.google.gapps has stopped" this statement appear sometimes
i really want a help please!

Comment: If you don't mind losing your data in internal storage and just want the phone to work again, flash a stock firmware with Odin to reset the phone back to fresh state.

Comment: it doesn't connect to odin because "USB debugging mode" is off and I can't reach it before phone restarting (sh** on all my data I want my phone working correctly)

Comment: Odin doesn't need the phone to boot normally at all. Get the right key combination when powering up the phone and you'' be in Download Mode for use with Odin.

Comment: I did what you said and showed that all threads completed with "PASS!"  green logo when the start rebooting i thought it has repaired but when i saw  the pattern lock I realized that nothing happened I start opening my lock the restart before I open it :-) I think there is no solution for that I'am really upset now However thank you for helping if you have any idea tell me pls

Comment: Have you wiped data / factory reset after using Odin? If Odin doesn't do that automatically for you then you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a stock ROM backup, then flash it with odin. Doing this will wipe all your data. But it is worth a try.
You will get installation procedures from [xda forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com)